# WPF radio buttons with converter - how all of my characters are becoming female

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a project (WPF with C# and XAML, using MVVM) and I have what I believe is a problem with a converter (from IValueConverter). Since I haven't been able to figure out the source of the problem, I'm coming here to ask you kind people.

What I have are two user controls. On the left side is a list of CharacterViewModel and on the right is a form of CharacterFormViewModel (both basically the same). If you click on an item in the list, it sends a CharacterViewModel to a mediator which passes it on to the form and displays it. It includes such details as first name, last name, age and gender. It works fine.

One thing I wanted to do was to have a radio button rather than a textbox for the Gender property. I left the original textbox in there too, just as a back up. I put in the radio buttons (three of them: male, female, other) and bound them, with a converter, to the view model on the form.

Let me give some code here:

Here is the radio button part of the XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Margin="3">
    <RadioButton GroupName="CharacterGender" Content="Male" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=genderConverterKey}, ConverterParameter=M}" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="CharacterGender" Content="Female" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=genderConverterKey}, ConverterParameter=F}" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="CharacterGender" Content="Other" IsChecked="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=genderConverterKey}, ConverterParameter=O}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

A little further up in the same usercontrol we have:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:GenderConverter x:Key="genderConverterKey" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And, of course, the converter itself:

```
class GenderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((string)parameter == value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Gender is of type 'Char', and I can say that the converter runs (I've used break points). It checks each of the parameters of the radio buttons, checks against the view model and then checks the right one. And that also seems to work.

**The problem:** and this only happens when using the radio buttons and converter, not without them. The problem is that, when I select a male character, somewhere in the process they switch to being female.

I can provide more information about this, since I've been looking at it for a while.

Something seems to be calling this code, but for some reason I can't tell what:

```
public char Gender
{
    get { return Character.Gender; }
    set
    {
        if (Character.Gender != value)
        {
            Character.Gender = value;
            MessageBox.Show("Changing character to: " + value.ToString());
            RaisePropertyChanged("Gender");
        }
    }
}
```

It's just a wrapper and isn't anything special. If I select a female, the message box pops up once and says 'Changing character to: F'. If I select a male, it says 'Changing character to: M' then straight after (and without my doing anything), pops up once more with 'Changing character to: F'. So the male characters are definitely male, but something's getting changed somewhere.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Oq0.png) shows the call stack with a couple of notes from me. I don't know what the 'external code' is doing, but it seems to be resetting the Gender.

To confirm: this does not happen if I remove the radio buttons and the converter, i.e. in the situation where I was just showing Gender using a regular textbox. Now I have both a radio button and a textbox. The data for Gender can be set using said textbox since it is editable but I don't do anything with that.

I hope I've provided enough information here to help someone to help me out. If not, I can provide more.

Some obvious things that I have tried: I removed the existing Gender textbox on the chance that somehow that was causing and update on the property. The problem still exists. I have also tried selecting all of the male characters (there are three), and the problem persists with each.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What are you doing in the Character.Gender setter? Try to simply set a _gender backing field in the property.

Comment: That is the CharacterViewModel Gender setter. This accesses the Character Gender setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your ConvertBack returns the parameter without respect to the actual `IsChecked` value.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if ((bool)value)
        return parameter;

    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

Please try, maybe I overlooked something different.

Comment: I'm afraid my Gender value isn't boolean. Would that still work? It seems like this might be a promising avenue.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner in `ConvertBack` the input value comes from `IsChecked`, so this has nothing to do with your Gender value (which is given in `parameter`). Still might be worth to go like `var isChecked = value as bool?; if (isChecked.GetValueOrDefault())`

Comment: I just went with your suggestion as is, and it worked like a charm. Thanks for taking the time to help!